# Reading files from AWS S3 in Golang

Tags: go, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to deploy a golang code on Heroku. My code needs a text file as input and I need to fetch this text file from S3 bucket. My go-code takes the filename as input, Can someone provide a code snippet for reading a file from S3 and storing its contents into a file?

My GOlang code-

```
  func getDomains(path string) (lines []string, Error error) {

    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }

    return lines, scanner.Err()
}

func Process(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {


    urls := make(chan *Http, Threads*10)
    list, err := getDomains("**NEED A TEXT FILE FROM S3 HERE as an argument**")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < Threads; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for url := range urls {
                url.DNS()
            }

            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(list); i++ {
        Progress := fmt.Sprintln(w, len(list))
        urls <- &Http{Url: list[i], Num: Progress}
    }

    close(urls)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("\r%s", strings.Repeat(" ", 100))
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "\rTask completed.\n")
}
```

Can someone suggest a good library for **reading** the file from S3 into a text file? I cannot download the file from S3 because I have to deploy it on Heroku.

A code snippet for example will be highly appreciated!

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go.

Comment: There is a download function available in the aws docs, I need a function for just reading the file

Comment: [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.GetObject) fetches an object from S3.

Answer (score 20):

The code snippet below should work (given that you have installed the proper dependencies):

```
    package main

    import (
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
        "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"

        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
    )

    func main() {
        // NOTE: you need to store your AWS credentials in ~/.aws/credentials

        // 1) Define your bucket and item names
        bucket := "<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>"
        item   := "<YOUR_ITEM_NAME>"

        // 2) Create an AWS session
        sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
                Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
        )

        // 3) Create a new AWS S3 downloader 
        downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)


        // 4) Download the item from the bucket. If an error occurs, log it and exit. Otherwise, notify the user that the download succeeded.
        file, err := os.Create(item)
        numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
            &s3.GetObjectInput{
                Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
                Key:    aws.String(item),
        })

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to download item %q, %v", item, err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Downloaded", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")

    }
```

For more details you can check the [AWS Go SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html) and the [Github Example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/go/example_code/s3/s3_download_object.go)

Comment: Where did `file` come from?

Comment: From the Github example

Comment: file points to localfile where the object has been downloaded to. So, this line file, err := os.Create(item) should've been file, err := os.Create("item_local"). Now when you run the above program it would download  to item_local and place it from where ever you're running your program from.

Comment: Why is this the highest voted? The original question is about `reading` but this answer is about `downloading`!

Answer (score 16):

Using current stable AWS lib for go:

```
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    ....
    }))


svc := s3.New(sess)

rawObject, err := svc.GetObject(
                &s3.GetObjectInput{
                    Bucket: aws.String("toto"),
                    Key:    aws.String("toto.txt"),
                })

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(rawObject.Body)
myFileContentAsString := buf.String()
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function for getting an object **using V2 of the SDK** (adapted from examples in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2):

Note: No Error handling - demo code only.

```
package s3demo

import (
    "os"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func GetObjectWithV2SDKDemo() {
    bucket := "YOUR_BUCKET"
    key := "YOUR_OBJECT_KEY"
    fileName := "YOUR_FILE_PATH"

    // may need AWS_PROFILE and AWS_REGION populated as environment variables
    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to load config, " + err.Error())
    }

    svc := s3.New(cfg)
    ctx := context.Background()
    req := svc.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })

    resp, err := req.Send(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    s3objectBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // create file
    f, err := os.Create(fileName)
    defer f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bytesWritten, err := f.Write(s3objectBytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Fetched %d bytes for S3Object\n", bytesWritten)
    fmt.Printf("successfully downloaded data from %s/%s\n to file %s", bucket, key, fileName)
}
```

Comment: This is now a bit outdated (e.g., the `s3.New(cfg)` is now `s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)`, etc.). Probably better to follow the examples in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/tree/main/example/service/s3 directly.